# Loaded Library cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c, dlopen

I copy pasted the code from [How would a loaded library function call a symbol in the main application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392416/how-would-a-loaded-library-function-call-a-symbol-in-the-main-application) to help me understand how loaded libraries work. But when I tried to run it, it says it cannot find the file, although the file is right there in the current directory when I do ls

```
@APG9591:/mnt/c/Users/fried/Desktop/KI3/Game$ gcc -shared -olibdlo.so dlo.c
    /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccpGxAlo.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /tmp/ccpGxAlo.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
@APG9591:/mnt/c/Users/fried/Desktop/KI3/Game$ gcc -shared -fPIC -olibdlo.so dlo.c
@APG9591:/mnt/c/Users/fried/Desktop/KI3/Game$ gcc -ldl -rdynamic main.c
    /tmp/ccHtUgDf.o: In function `main':
    main.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `dlopen'
    main.c:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `dlerror'
    main.c:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `dlerror'
    main.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `dlsym'
    main.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `dlerror'
    main.c:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `dlclose'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
@APG9591:/mnt/c/Users/fried/Desktop/KI3/Game$ gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl -rdynamic main.c
@APG9591:/mnt/c/Users/fried/Desktop/KI3/Game$ ls
    AI_A.c  AI_B.c  AI_C.c  a.out  dlo.c  Game.c  Game.h  libdlo.so  main.c  runGame.c
@APG9591:/mnt/c/Users/fried/Desktop/KI3/Game$ ./a.out
    libdlo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
@APG9591:/mnt/c/Users/fried/Desktop/KI3/Game$
```

libdlo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

why couldn't the program find the file libdlo.so? How do I fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Your local directory is not one of folders where Linux look for libraries. Move your lib into `/usr/lib` for example or take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux)

Comment: In your dlopen call you need to specify relative path if you want to load the library from current directory. EX: `./libdlo.so`

Comment: Reorder you linking command: `gcc -rdynamic main.c -ldl`

Answer (score 3):

OS does not look for libraries in your local directory, either

1) Move your lib into `/usr/lib`

2) In the dlopen call specify the relative path `"./libdlo.so"`

.

Thanks to lps and ankur for the answers

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851184/dlopen-failed-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/49084492#49084492). I recently encounted the same probelm and it will definitely help.

After reading that, I recommend you to use the `-rpath` option.

Just for fun, you can also use `ldconfig $(pwd)` to solve this, and I think sometimes this method is better.

For more information, please read [the linux how-to documentation on library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html), which tells a lot about static library, shared library and dynamically linked library.

For more and more information, please read [Better understanding Linux secondary dependencies solving with examples](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/), which explores deeper in libraries that are linked by dynamic linker, that is , shared library and dynamically linked library.