# How to load correct type information of shared lib opened by dlopen in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, dlopen

I used `dlopen` to load multiple shared libraries which use same type name with different layout in each module. There is no problem when just compiling and running example, but I can't load correct type information for each module in gdb when debugging.

Here is an example I've used to reproduce this situation.
(I've adopted an example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/392421 with modification to add multiple module.)

moduleA.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum myEnum {
    MY_A=1,
    MY_B=2,
    MY_C=3,
    MY_D=4,
    MY_E=5
};
void callback(int v);
extern "C" void foo(void)
{
    puts("Hello, I'm a shared library A");
    callback(MY_D);
}
```

moduleB.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum myEnum {
    MY_A=1,
    MY_B=2,
    MY_C=100,  // different enumeration
    MY_D=101,
    MY_E=102
};

void callback(int v);

extern "C" void foo(void)
{
    puts("Hello, I'm a shared library B");
    callback(MY_D);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


void callback(int v) {
    printf("here, i'm back and MY_D is %d\n", v);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *handleA, *handleB;
    void (*fooA)(void);
    void (*fooB)(void);
    char *errorA;
    char *errorB;

    // Use moduleA
    handleA = dlopen("./libmoduleA.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    *(void **) (&fooA) = dlsym(handleA, "foo");
    (*fooA)();

    // Use moduleB
    handleB = dlopen("./libmoduleB.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    *(void **) (&fooB) = dlsym(handleB, "foo");
    (*fooB)();

    dlclose(handleA);
    dlclose(handleB);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I've compile and run above example, I've got following result as expected.

```
$ g++ -g -shared -Wall -Werror -fpic -o libmoduleA.so moduleA.cpp
$ g++ -g -shared -Wall -Werror -fpic -o libmoduleB.so moduleB.cpp
$ g++ -g -rdynamic -o a.out main.cpp -ldl
$ ./a.out 
Hello, I'm a shared library A
here, i'm back and MY_D is 4
Hello, I'm a shared library B
here, i'm back and MY_D is 101
```

However when I've tried to use gdb to debug, type information in gdb is not correctly shown for each module.

For example, different `myEnum` type are defined in module A and B above, e.g. MY_C and later have different value.
If I use `gdb` to test `myEnum` type for each module as below, I can't fetch correct enumeration for module B, which is loaded later than module A.

```
$ gdb a.out
(gdb) b foo
Function "foo" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (foo) pending.
(gdb) r

Breakpoint 1, foo () at moduleA.cpp:15
15          puts("Hello, I'm a shared library A");
(gdb) ptype myEnum
type = enum myEnum {MY_A = 1, MY_B, MY_C, MY_D, MY_E}
(gdb) p/x MY_D
$3 = 0x4
(gdb) n
Hello, I'm a shared library A
16          callback(MY_D);
(gdb) n
here, i'm back and MY_D is 4
17      }
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, foo () at moduleB.cpp:15
15          puts("Hello, I'm a shared library B");
(gdb) ptype myEnum
type = enum myEnum {MY_A = 1, MY_B, MY_C, MY_D, MY_E}
(gdb) p/x MY_D
$4 = 0x4
(gdb) n
Hello, I'm a shared library B
16          callback(MY_D);
(gdb) 
here, i'm back and MY_D is 101
17      }
(gdb)
```

I would like to see correct `enum myEnum` information where `MY_D` is `101`, not `4` for module B.
It seems that correct type information is loaded for module B, if I close moulde A before loading module B. However I want to use both module without closing.

Is there any way to load type information for module B in gdb without closing module A ?

Comment: You can put each module content in it's own namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I can't choose this approach..  I found this issue on a large open source and those types are defines in a header file with same namespace with `#ifdef` to differentiate layout. In addition, the type should be same, because there is another shared module to exploit the type.

Comment: It seems that there is a manual way to workaround this issue.
We can use`nosharedlibrary` to unload existing type info and load type info by `sharedlibrary regex`

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html

However it's not convenient and sometimes confusing to load type information manually.